How can you determine the optimal alphabet for a given string?
Currently I'm studying the Huffman Code and came over a question, which i dont know how to solve, for a given string s, how can you find an alphabet sigma for that the huffman compression of your data is minimal?
One example would be this:
s= "ababaab"
with sigma = {a,b}
a= 0
b= 1
=> 0101001
with sigma = {ab,a}
ab= 0
a=  1
=> 0010 (length is smaller than the first)

Because of this behavior my idea would be to compare all diffrent combination and find the shortes code.
But that wont work, because sigma = {ababaab} would be this shortest of length 1, but this is not what we want, because the length of saving this huffman code would be as long, as saving the data itself.

One way to do it is to take the unique symbols used one at a time, two at a time and three at a time and compute the frequencies that each of these patterns is seen in the source string. In general you also need a symbol to indicate start of Huffman code as well. Most Huffman coders merely allocate most frequent bytes to shortest codes and longest codes to the least frequent bytes. Many JPEG encoders use default Huffman coding tables which isn't optimal but is faster and generally good enough.

I had the same idea, but computing all the possible frequencies will take n^k (n all the possible symbols and k the number of symbols) time, because you have to go trough all the possibility's. Even if you have all the possible combination, how can you find out which combination is the best. If you have the string s = "abca", then you would have {a,b,c,ab,bc,ca,abc,bca,abca} as possible combinations, but if you take bc, than you can't choose any other than a in order to represent s.

There are two competing sizes here and it is their sum that you need to optimise. A greedy heuristic will probably be close enough to optimal not to matter. IOW classical allocation of the Huffman codes. There is the size of the Huffman encoded bitstream and the size of the dictionary to consider. IRL you are unlikely to see much benefit from going beyond n^3 (and n^2 might be good enough for all practical purposes). There may be more than one solution too if some tokens appear the same number of times... Bytewise Huffman encoding will give you an easy target to aim to beat.
